# How to generate the combinations of the following in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I saw similar questions to this however my case scenario is different

I have an array of this structure:

```
var options = {
  'color': ['red', 'green'],
  'size': ['L', 'XS'],
  'dimensions': ['dim1']
};
```

I want to generate the combinations in the following structure

```
 {
 'red,L,dim1': [
  {'color': 'red'},
  {'size': 'L'},
  {'dimensions': 'dim1'},
 ],
 'red,XS,dim1': [
  {'color': 'red'},
  {'size': 'XS'},
  {'dimensions': 'dim1'},
 ],
 'green,L,dim1': [
  {'color': 'green'},
  {'size': 'L'},
  {'dimensions': 'dim1'},
 ],
 'green,XS,dim1': [
  {'color': 'green'},
  {'size': 'XS'},
  {'dimensions': 'dim1'},
 ],
};
```

How can i achieve this? 
I appreciate any help

Comment: Please show us what code have you written so far to solve your problem and where did you get struck?

Comment: One simple approach would be to loop through the color array, then nested inside this loop, go through the size array and then nested in that array, go through the dimensions array. In the most inner loop you have access to all values (color, size, dimension) and then you can join those values to a key and add it to a new object, which was defined before the loops.

Comment: But really, you should try something and show us your approach in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so after spending sometime i figured it out

```
options = ['color', 'size'];
optionsValues= [['Red','Blue'], ['L', 'XS']];

function combination() {
    var r = [], arg = arguments[0], max = arg.length-1;
    function helper(arr, i) {
        for (var j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
            var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
            var obj = {};
            obj[options[i]] = arg[i][j];
            a.push(obj); 
            if (i==max){
                str = '';
                for(var c = a.length - 1 ; c >= 0; c--){
                  if(c == 0){
                    str += a[c][options[c]];
                  }else{
                    str += a[c][options[c]] + ',';
                  }
                }
                r[str] = a;
            }
            else
                helper(a, i+1);
        }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
}

console.log(combination(optionsValues));
```